Should weekly topics be extended to monthly topics, and should we employ banners to announce the topic?
Our second weekly-topic-challenge got remarkably little attention after a relatively successful first weekly challenge.  At least two possibly courses of action come to mind.
First, we could use regular banners appearing at the top to announce the topic.  Despite this being against official SE policy, other sites have also found that banners are very helpful if not necessary to advertise the existence of a topic.
Second, we could extend each topic challenge from weekly to monthly.  For a site such as QF, where relatively few independent topics truly exist, a monthly topic may make more sense.  There's also a great deal of overhead for me involved with setting up each weekly topic, and transitioning to monthly would make that overhead a lot more manageable.

Yes to both points.

I also agree...

Please allow me to take a moment to go into why using the banner is against the official SE policy.
The main reason you don't want to be using the system banner to announce events is that you will teach your community to tune them out. These banners cannot be dismissed and when people see them point to things they're not interested in or just don't need to be reminded about, they will start ignoring them.
It's unfortunate that there isn't a better way to announce events right now. I suggest voicing your support for this feature request and sticking with tagging the meta posts as featured to make them appear on the sidebar.

Great idea. Thx.
